# По какому критерию лучше выбрать запись в WordPress

Tags: php, html, xml, wordpress

У меня есть отдельный шаблон для вывода отдельной страницы, а также главная страница, где выводиться превью записей с разных категорий.

Сайт на 3 языках - реализовывать решили через мультисайт. Проблема в том, что для каждой версии сайта нужна отдельная тема, и нужно создавать заново в каждом сайте категории и записи заново. Соответственно id категорий и записей будет для каждой версией сайта разные.

Думал делать выборку по названию категории или статьи но, если пользователь переименует название статьи или категории, то код не будет работать.

По какому критерию лучше выбрать запись в WordPress?

Comment: Я не понял вопроса. Но почему решили сделать мультисайт вместо того, чтобы взять какой-нибудь [polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/), скажем?

Comment: Решили через мультисайт так как используем rtl языки.Вопрос в том, что лучше указывать в get_post или в подобных фукциях, номер поста,категории....или их название.

Comment: "Решили через мультисайт так как используем rtl языки." - вообще ни о чем мне не говорит, на обычной установке ровно так же должно работать. `get_post` и большинство других функций иначе как через ID не работает, так что у вас выбор не особо богатый.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, если вы хотите делать все это стоит делать на WPML или аналогах. Я так полагаю вам необходимо состыковать все категории на этих сайтах, но для этого вам придется писать. Я так понимаю вам стоит делать выборку с трех сайтов и делать им дополнительный id при join. А по ней уже идет синхронизация постов.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую в данной ситуации прибегнуть к [WPML](https://wpml.org/) - WordPress Multilingual Plugin.

Вы сейчас оптимизируя вот такие запросы, нагородите их еще больше. Поверьте - WPML окупается на первом же сайте.